# Is there a way I can force the robots to be already localized?

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, nav2d-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want the robots to be already localized when I start the program. Is there any way for this, so that I do not have to move the robot manually and localize it?

I have two robots and in order to explore with the second robot, I have to localize it first which takes a lot of time. By the time I localize it, the other robot explores whole of the map.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221306/is-there-a-way-i-can-force-the-robots-to-be-already-localized-?/) by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl), you can set initial pose estimate of the robot by publishing to `/initialpose` topic. Also there is a visual tool for this in rviz, which is named as "2D Pose Estimate". Is this what you need?

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-11-23**:
Yes, I tried clicking he 2D Pose Estimate in hope that my localization will be done faster. But there is no decrease in localization time. By the time I localize it, the other robot finishes whole map. Is there a way, i can manually localize before the program starts?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-23**:
You can try publishing on `/initialpose` programmatically or on terminal instead of using rviz. This may result in faster localization. Or you may make the other robot wait until first robot localizes.